# How can I select current element in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I make menu and I want to when I hover in text on jquery, changed color. That's no problem until now. But the problem is, all element's changed color. I just want to change current element. Thanks :).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $('ul#menu').hover(function()
    {
        $('ul#menu li a').css({'transition':'2s','color':'#900'});  

    },function()
    {
        $('ul#menu li a').css({'color':'#fff'});    

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this` inside your `hover` function:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('ul#menu li a').hover(function()
                          {
    $(this).css({'transition':'2s','color':'#900'});  
  },function()
                          {
    $(this).css({'color':'#fff'});    
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend doing this with CSS.

```
ul#menu li a{
   color:#900;
   transition:2s;
}

ul#menu li a:hover{
   color:#fff;
}
```